# AWS Glue, transfer CSV to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I only have the AWS CLI to do this labor.

I cant get the JDBC URL like say in this link (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html#obtain-jdbc-url) because i dont have access to the web console of AWS and i think need to use in this command (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/create-connection.html)

I am doing the correct things or I'm doing everything wrong?

Comment: Please can you tell us why you cannot access the console? its going to be really tough to do this with cli.  why do you need glue, why not just a redshift copy command from s3? - also please put in your links and commands into your question rather than hyperlinks.

Comment: The problem to access to the web console is because the client dont have access or is the information that i have.

We are using AWS Glue because it is a customer requirement, we need to migrate Teradata data. We already get the data to a CSV and the idea is to load this CSV to Redshift using Glue

Comment: if you have csv data, then that is NOT teradata. and you can upload it to s3 then COPY it to redshift. the only need for glue would be if you needed to transform the data first.

Comment: Besides Job Scott's comments, please note that if its a client requirement to use Glue for this, let some cloud admin from the client side create/configure a JDBC connections to Redshift, and you can use it.  Maybe you can refer this URL to create connections : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-connections.html.  You may require some IAM roles with assumeRole to run Glue jobs, do you have them from client?